# Make condition right using SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, ado.net, ado

```
var a = "1";
var b = "2";
var c = "3";

var name = authResult.ExtraData["email"];

string connectionString = null;

SqlConnection cnn;
SqlCommand cmd;
string sql = null;
SqlDataReader reader;

connectionString = "Data Source = dj0043\\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = XXXX; Integrated Security = True";
sql = "Select EmployeeRoles.RoleId From EmployeeList Inner Join EmployeeRoles on EmployeeList.EmployeeId = EmployeeRoles.EmployeeId Where EmailId = name";

cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

try
{
    cnn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader == a)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Employee", "Home"));
        }
        else if (sql == b)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
        }
        else if (sql == c)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    cnn.Close();
}
```

In this if any user have the 1 id will be redirected to that page and same as other vice versa.

Can anyone tell me how to make `SqlDataReader` work with this condition?

Comment: This condition is not working it is showing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your SQL query is not correct. You should send a `@name` parameter into the query.

I prefer to do it this way as it's much more cleaner

```
var a = "1";
var b = "2";
var c = "3";

var name = authResult.ExtraData["email"];
var connectionString = "Data Source = dj0043\\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = XXXX; Integrated Security = True";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
           connection.Open();
           using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
           {
               cmd.CommandText = "Select EmployeeRoles.RoleId From EmployeeList Inner Join EmployeeRoles on EmployeeList.EmployeeId = EmployeeRoles.EmployeeId Where EmailId = @name";
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;


               using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
               {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                       if (reader["RoleId"].ToString() == a)
                       {
                          return Redirect(Url.Action("Employee", "Home"));
                       }
                       else if (reader["RoleId"].ToString() == b)
                       {
                          return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
                       }
                       else if (reader["RoleId"].ToString() == c)
                       {
                          return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
                       }
                    }
               }
          }
}
```

Comment: This condition is not working it is showing an error

Comment: Its is till showing the int error in if condition. I think because the var i am initializing is of string type and unable to convert data reader value intonint and unable to compare.... If anyother reason do suggest and

Comment: i have made changes regarding int but it is showing and error about unable to binding on the null refrence exception

Comment: @RizwanWani I have updated my answer by changing my datatype to string. Null reference  issue might comes from null object in the code.  Check whether your connection string is valid. Then make sure 'authResult.ExtraData["email"]' return the correct value. And is there any possibility that your roleId is null?

Comment: No role id is not null ... And in authResult.Extradata[''email''] i am getting the email of the user but... I don't know why it is showing this issue as the reader is not being executed the debugger is not debugging the reader.

Comment: @RizwanWani which line does the error null reference occurred?

Comment: @RizwanWani Dont forget to mark this as an answer if it's the one.

Comment: Yes i would like to ask you more questions will you help me. Out

Comment: @RizwanWani if it's a whole new question, unrelated to this one, just open a new question in SO and all of us will try to help you.